# Why doesn't Icecast respond to the 'OPTIONS' request sent by browsers in preflight check for CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors, icecast

I am working on a player for an Icecast stream and trying to get metadata from the stream.  The player will be on `example.fm` while the stream is at `stream.example.fm/93.mp3`.

According to Icecast documentation I need to include the `Icy-MetaData: 1` header in the request to receive metadata in the stream.  The problem arises when I include that header.

**Simple fetch works, but not with header**

A simple request such as `fetch("https://stream.example.fm/96.mp3")` returns a valid 200 response.

But this code does not work:

```
let Heads = new Headers({
        "Icy-MetaData": "1"
      });
      fetch("https://stream.example.fm/96.mp3", {
          headers: Heads
        })
```

**Verifying Server Headers**

Excecuting `curl -H "Icy-MetaData: 1" -v "https://stream.example.fm/96.mp3" >/dev/null` confirms that

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Icy-MetaData
```

are present in the streaming server's headers.

**Preflight Check**

The problem seems to be with the 'OPTIONS' request the browsers send for the preflight check.  The custom header triggers this.  I did a test using curl:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS https://stream.example.fm/96.mp3 -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: icy-metadata' -H 'Origin: https://example.fm'
```

And I get an error:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Is this an Icecast bug or am I missing something in the configuration of my server?

Comment: Have you checked that your request doesn't include *other* headers that aren't allowed?

Comment: Just verified that fixing the cases to match does not help

Comment: Network tab in chrome shows only `icy-metadata: 1` header.

Comment: Yeah, often implementations do case-insensitivity by going to all lower or all upper.

Comment: [does not work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not a useful description of the problem. In what way is it failing? You implied the problem was CORS related: What CORS related error messages are logged? What does the Network tab show for the request and response?

Comment: Ok, see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, you will have to upgrade your icecast server. I just bumped into the same problem, and the upcoming 2.5 will fix this issue.

2.4.4 (the latest stable at the time of writing this) returns an empty response to an OPTION request, just like you (and I) noticed.

I'm testing 2.5 now, don't want to come to early conclusions but so far it seems to be working nicely. Be prepared for a couple configuration changes though.